# My program closes on name resolution error

Tags: python, exception, mqtt, paho

My program closes on name resolution error. This could happen when there is no internet or the other server is down. I want program to raise exception, but not exit. How do I do this. I'm using paho client.

```
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", 
line 760, in connect
return self.reconnect()
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", 
line 887, in reconnect
sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), 
source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 694, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 733, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, 
flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: You need to include your code as well as the error if you want us to help

Comment: When exception is raised, the program exits. Unless you catch the exception. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html